# (Change) event won't fire function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an issue regarding triggering a function after changing the value in a dropdown. I got the following code:

dropdown.component.html

```
<bg-dropdown
  (change)="addCriteria($event.target.value)"
  [items]="logicOperators"
  id="logicOperator"
></bg-dropdown>
```

[items] is an array of items from my database elsewhere (shows up fine)

dropdown.component.ts

```
public addCriteria(value: string): void {
   console.error(value);
}
```

This can also be seen in the following StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iczepg

However, I don't get anything printed out in the console whenever I change the dropdown. I've tried to find a solution for the issue but fallen short after trying for some time. Someone who can help?

Comment: Hey :) can you provide us a stackblitz with an example of your problem :) ?

Comment: Sure, will provide one ASAP :)

Comment: well does bg-dropdown have a change property?

Comment: Your stackblitz throws an error

Comment: Hm, not sure about it. It's a custom dropdown we've made in my company. I'm fairly new to Angular, so should this be located in the bgdropdown.component.ts?

Comment: We need the code for that custom dropdown. In your Stackblitz, you have to set that dropdown up as if it were a component belonging to that application for it to work - or install the NPM package if your company published the library to the official npm registry.

Comment: Hm yeah. Trying to find out what to copy is quite messy since the solution is quite big and is wired up in a quite complex way. I think I'll ask someone from my company instead, since I think it would take quite some time to set up a StackBlitz for it.

Thanks anyways though. Happy new year.